# Covert object and its array to JSON (JQuery AJAX CALL)

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object, push

I have multiple sections like student , address , result 
now student has one object called "Student"
second object called "address"
third object "result" is list of array

and I would like to put all three object into one object and then convert into JSON object
Step 1:

```
var allInOneObject = []; 
var studentObject = {};
var addressObject = {};
var resultObject = [];
studentObject = $("#studentData").serializeObject();
addressObject = $("#addressData").serializeObject();
```

now I have multiple records in result so I used array to store records

```
resultObject.push({result1:"11",result2:"22"});
resultObject.push({result1:"33",result2:"44"});
resultObject.push({result1:"55",result2:"66"});
```

Then I tried to combined all in one object that is allInOneObject
so

```
allInOneObject.push({student:studentObject});
allInOneObject.push({address:addressObject});
allInOneObject.push({result:resultObject});

var sendData = {base :allInOneObject }
var dataToJSON = JSON.stringify(sendData);
```

dataToJSON has proper values of student and address , result has blank value in JSON format
like

```
{
"result":[]
}
```

**** above JSON issue resolved.**
Its working now ,Next task to call Method using Jquery

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "StudentRegister.aspx/SaveStudent",
                    data: sendData,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert("successfully done");
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
                return false;
```

It says Internal server 500 error.

```
[WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod]
 public static AjaxResponse<Student> SaveStudent(Student sd)
 {
            var AjaxResponse = new AjaxResponse<Student>();
            return AjaxResponse;
}
```

I am using VS 2012. Application is running on 38301 port.

```
In Browser console :
POST http:// localhost :38301/Student/StudentRegister.aspx/SaveStudent 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous function) StudentRegister.aspx:79
n.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3
n.event.add.r.handle
```

TIA

Please correct me , if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsbin.com/toqegeko/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks Felix , actually its working now...dont know how ...I need one more cup of coffee.